# I want to show 1 and partially the next image in the fotorama main gallery of Magento

Tags: magento2.4, frontend, fotorama, adobe-commerce, pdp

In the PDP, I want to show the first main image and the partial second image in the product gallery of fotorama for Magento 2.4.6. Is this achievable?[image: pdp gallery]